# JPA and Jackson with Inheritance - How to get this to work?

Tags: java, json, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I think this can be better explained with an example(code is below). Suppose I have BaseClass and some sub-classes like Employee, Contractor etc. I do not want a database table for BaseClass(Hence using @MappedSuperClass).
BaseClass has some common fields, but entityType is not a valid database field in any subclass like Employee, Contrator (Hence I denoted it as @Transient).
Now I get back a json that has all the Employee values, it does not have endDate value that is in the BaseClass. I want to set the BaseClass's common fields like endDate in the Employee class and save it to the Employee table.

When retrieving I want to retrieve all Employees that have an endDate as some value. This should be possible because I did save the endDate when saving my Employee records.

Additional Info: I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm using openAPI and I understood that I need this discriminator column to have a super class-sub class relationship generated - [Inheritance from empty abstract class using openapi 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105116/inheritance-from-empty-abstract-class-using-openapi-3-0/76105322?noredirect=1#comment134400499_76105322).

```
      @JsonIgnoreProperties(
  value = "entityType", // ignore manually set entityType, it will be automatically generated by Jackson during serialization
  allowSetters = true // allows the entityType to be set during deserialization
)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "entityType", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Employee.class, name = "Employee")
   @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Contractor.class, name = "Contractor")
}) 
  @jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass
  public abstract BaseClass{
   //common to all sub-classes
   LocalDate endDate;

   /**
    Gets or Sets entityType
   */
   public enum EntityTypeEnum {
    Employee("Employee");
    Contractor("Contractor");

    private String value;

    EntityTypeEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static EntityTypeEnum fromValue(String value) {
      for (EntityTypeEnum b : EntityTypeEnum.values()) {
        if (b.value.equals(value)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }
  }

     @JsonProperty("entityType")
     @jakarta.persistence.Transient
     private EntityTypeEnum entityType;

    }

    public Employee extends BaseClass {...}

    public Contractor extends BaseClass{...}
```

How would this deserializing work if I know that I'm de-serializing Employee.class, but the Json for employees that I receive does not have the entityType as a property at all? Currently I get 'missing type id property 'entityType''
I want to de-serialize a json of Employees to List class. The Json does not have entityType or any superclass(i.e. BaseClass from the above example) fields.

So to summarize, I want Jackson and JPA to play nicely with each other.

1. I want to Jackson to correctly read a json, where the json has only the Employee related values(no superclass values yet) (At runtime I will know that I have Employee.class).
2. I want to save this to the Employees table after setting my own values like endDate(which are in the BaseClass).
3. I want to retrive this later, from the Employees table, knowing taht I have the endDate and Employee.class value at runtime.

Hope this makes sense. If not let me rephrase my questions:
OpenAPI requires me to use the discriminator, in this case we call it entityType, for the inheritance to work when the classes are generated. But when I do that, Jackson complains that it cannot find the property id entityType when serializing a json. The json obviously does not have a field called entityType because we created this field.
I tired variaous apporached including using :
1.

```
 objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

2. 

```
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

3. 

Adding the following to the top of the BaseClass:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
  value = "entityType", // ignore manually set entityType, it will be automatically generated by Jackson during serialization
  allowSetters = true // allows the entityType to be set during deserialization
)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "entityType")
```

and I still get this error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class Employee]: missing type id property 'entityType'

Comment: could you post the code that about your use case

Comment: @similieis2333 which code? I mean code about what? I thought my example was code

Answer (score 1):

> How would this deserializing work if I know that I'm de-serializing Employee.class, but the Json for employees that I receive does not have the entityType as a property at all?

If *you* know that the JSON represents an `Employee` and not a `Contractor` (e.g. based on the source) then you can invoke the mapper passing the `Employee` class.  But if you are using this in a general case where you want the deserialization to return either `Employee` or `Contractor` then there needs to be a *discriminator* so the deserializer can choose the correct concrete class itself.  (Consider the case where two subclasses have identical fields, but nevertheless are being modelled as different classes - there would be no way for the serializer to guess which class it should instantiate.)

(1) I suggest that you accept the permanent addition of `entityType` in the superclass - and in particular you should serialize it so that the JSON then carries the type info.  And (2) you should remove the `@JsonIgnoreProperties...` so that the type info *is* available to the deserializer.

To enforce the correct type automatically here's what you can do: (3) `BaseClass` should require `entityType` in its constructor and you can code the correct type in `Employee` and `Contractor` constructors so they pass the type to `BaseClass`.

As you are now managing the `entityType` yourself, I think (4) the `@JsonTypeInfo` should be:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "entityType", visible = true)
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

This approach is compatible with JPA.  I am using Jackson, Spring Data and Mongo as my backing store.  In the case of Mongo, Spring adds a `_class` field as its own different way to handle the de/serialisation.  The `_class` field occurs in the database but is not in the java object.  So this approach is using two parallel methods of type management and they do not collide; in fact this allows finer-grain control should you need slightly different external (JSON) models compared to the backing store.

Comment: 'I suggest that you accept the permanent addition of entityType in the superclass' - The problem is that the json is returned by an external API and I cannot modify it.

Comment: OK, so how can you/the machine distinguish a `Employee` from a `Contractor`?  Can provide some specimen JSON for both?  There is another way...

Comment: OR to you always know at the point you invoke the deserialization what the content is: Employee or Contractor?

Comment: Yes I do know at the point of de-serialization what content it is, because the generic class gets the class type of the expected json as well. I can remove entityType, but then the openAPI doesn't generate the class hierarchy without the discriminator. I guess I can keep the BaseClass outside the OpenAPI somehow.

Comment: 'then you can invoke the mapper passing the Employee class. -> how to do that? I tired          TypeReference<List<Employee>> typeReference= new TypeReference<>(){};
objectMapper.readValue(new File(...), typeReference);